# What is the classifying noun for a person who is both a project team member and a consumer of the final product?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

In an example scenario, two people, say a capenter and a plumber, are both working on a shopping mall construction project.  The carpenter, lives in a foreign land, will return home when her direct involvement in the project is complete, while the plumber is a local lad and is looking forward to taking advantage of the wonderful purchasing opportunities the new mall will offer.

Both the carpenter and the plumber are project team members.

What single term describes the plumber's involvement with the project as both a project team member and a consumer?

Comment: The plumber's *got stakes* in the project. He's *invested* in the project. Don't know about a single noun.

Comment: We use the term "back yard" to indicate feeling to the effect of something because of proximity to it. If it's a bad thing, then "not in my backyard" (NIMBY). The plumber is working in his *own back yard*.

Answer (score 2):

***(dual) stakeholder***

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stakeholder):

> **stakeholder** *noun*
>
> a person such as an **employee**, **customer**, or **citizen** who is
>   involved with an organization, society, etc. and therefore has
>   **responsibilities towards it** and an **interest in its success**

The interesting part is that in your example, both the carpenter and the plumber are stakeholders (as employees, **explicitly** having **responsibilities towards it**). Also, **implicit** is their **interest in its success**, to see their effort bear fruit.

However, the plumber **additionally** is a stakeholder with an ***explicit* interest in its success** as someone who is (*looking forward to be*) a customer. Also, as a local citizen, he perhaps has an **implict** interest in its success due to the associated developments it may bring.

Probably, you can call the plumber a ***dual* stakeholder**.

Note: Silenus did use the term *stakes* in an earlier comment.

Comment: Interesting idea.